# Why does FFT function return an integer?

Tags: fft

I have an FFT function that returns an integer. As far as i know, FFT takes a windowed audio segment and returns an array of the frequencies found within.

I have a function of this kind:

```
 fft (ar, ai, n, sw)
     register double *ar, //array real
            *ai; // array imaginary
     int     n; // window length
     double  sw; // return forwards or backwards FFT graph
 {

 ... the maths

 return(n);
 }
```

Why can an FFT return n and what is it?

the complete code is here towards the end of the page https://sites.google.com/site/kootsoop/Home/cohens_class_code

Comment: Note that the proper FFT is an inplace operation, so the input array probably contains the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFT is an inplace operation, so the input array should contains the answer. Check with a simple example (say sine wave  --> two peaks for neg. and pos. frequencies)  whether the content changed after calling the function.